# PDO arrays and array_unique

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to return a list of course id's from my database with `PDO`. I can access the data, however, I only want to return an array of unique id's i.e.

This

```
1,2,2,3,4,4
```

Becomes

```
1,2,3,4
```

I'm using the code below

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT courseId from training');  
    $sth->execute();  
        $row = $sth->fetchAll();
        $result = array_unique($row);
        print_r($result);
```

But, it returns only 1 id:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [courseId] => 8 [0] => 8 ) )
```

If I `print_r` `$row` I can see all my courseId's

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick tip - when executing queries that don't require data binding, just use the method `query()` like this: `$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT courseId FROM training');`. To be more efficient, you can even populate the variable with the result of the query in the same line, like this: `$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT courseId FROM training')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you would be better off by doing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT courseId FROM training
```

That way the data coming from the database is already unique and there is no need to use `array_unique`.

Comment: Thanks Alec. I'll use that instead. I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with `array_unique` so I know for the future.

Answer (score 5):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are not reading the friendly [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on `array_unique`, where you can see this:

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1
>   === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same. The first element will be used.

Since `$result` contains arrays, and the string representation of each of them is the same ("Array" IIRC) then all the elements compare "equal" and only the first is left.

**How to solve the problem:** Several ways.

One would be to let the database do it for you with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Another would be to go from an array of arrays to an array of just ids, and then `array_unique` will work just fine. This can be simply done with a `foreach` loop, or (probably better) with `array_map`, e.g:

```
$ids = array_map(function($el) { return $el['courseId']; }, $row);
$unique = array_unique($ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the comaprison `array_unique` is using. I would just do this in the query by using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: See [Jon's Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9728089/215966) above... I didnt go into more detail because after i wrote the initial part of my answer there were 2 others containing the same detail and recommendation :-)